# Magento Admin not working - after deleted store from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1

I have created two store in magento and one store deleted by mistake without backup. Now showing this error

Please Help me how to solve.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please clean browser cache and var/cache/ If this not help, share your link

Ps.
I already checked your store if I check correct link from your avatar, cleaning browser cache will help. Or login via incognito mode.
I can see admin page.

Regards

Comment: Did you found solution?